# Unhandled exception in android notified by Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Trying my hand at Eclipse and Android.
When I save my file, however, eclipse screams about an unhandled exception.
When trying to add the catch bit, however, Eclipse tells me I have to delete the code
inside the try!

Anybody can please tell me what's going on? 
I am a newbie at both Java and Eclipse.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {       
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            todo_source = new ToDoListFile("todo.json" );
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Regards.

Comment: _When trying to add the catch bit, however, Eclipse tells me I have to delete the code inside the try!_ What exactly do you add as the _catch bit_, and what's the exact stuff that Eclipse says?

Comment: You cant use try without catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch the exception:

```
try{
    myStuff();
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). If that doesn't help, please show how you tried to catch the exception, and the exact message Eclipse gives you.

Comment: ok, what I was doing is simple: I was not using the brackets and the exception name, I was only writing "catch FileNotFoundException" instead of doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

when you choose to handle the exception in your code, you have to handle it in a catch block, currently you are not handling the exception. you just have a try block in which you put the piece of code which might throw an exception and a finally block which does nothing. catch the exception in the catch block and handle it(print the stacktrace of the exception).

```
 try
 {       
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  todo_source = new ToDoListFile("todo.json" );
 }
 catch(WhatEverException ex){
 ex.printStackTrace()
 }
```

Comment: After I woke up, I finally noticed my error :) I am giving the points to Niek as he came earlier - but really you would deserve them too :)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that you need to out serContentView outside the try block.
It could preve

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration is valid as long as the code inside the `try` block does not throw an exception. Probably the `new ToDoListFile("todo.json" );` throws an exception an you need to `catch` it